# Step up boost converter to increase amps keep voltage

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, voltage-regulator, amperage

I have a 48v 13ah lithium battery on 1800w motor with a 33 amp controller can I use DC to DC constant current boost converter to increase my amps to 30ah but keep my voltage the same? Or increase my voltage to say 60v 25ah? It's for an electric scooter.

Comment: What you ask is physically impossible.

Comment: Think about what you are asking.  If this worked, why would we need bigger batteries.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. Ah is a measure of energy when you also factor in voltage (Ah x V = watt-hours, or Wh.) Your pack has 624 Wh, and there’s no way to increase that other than getting a bigger pack.

If you meant boost the current with a step-down DC-DC, then yes, that’s possible. But your Wh will be the same, or even somewhat less due to losses in the conversion.

You will not get more current, power or energy by stepping up to 60V. In fact your current will be less. And again, there will be energy losses.

Your motor has a voltage rating with which it works best. The most efficient way to get the most out of your battery is to match that motor to the battery, or vice-versa. If your motor works best on 60V, upgrade your battery to 60V. Using a step-up to do that adds weight, complexity, cost and losses to your system.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand the difference between capacity and current.

The capacity of a battery is usually given in Ah or Wh. It's rating is how many power can be delivered over a time period. So in the ideal case a 100Ah battery could deliver 100A for an hour before being discharged. It could also deliver 60 000A for one minute. Of course, this is only in the theory of the unit itself. The battery has other specifications which are critical to answer your question.

What you are asking is NOT impossible! Or at least, you are not providing enough info for me to know if it's impossible. Increasing voltage or current can be done using DC-DC. So if your motor is 200V, you can convert it. But you will not gain power. You might increase the voltage of your battery but the total power will remain the same (minus losses) on the input and output of your regulator.

The main one is what is it's current discharge rating? Assuming, your battery can sustain the current before your regulator (boost significantly increase the input current).

Let say you have a 48V 13Ah battery, it will approximately (ideal) to 624Wh. Your motor is 1800W meaning that in the ideal case, your battery will last 20 minutes. No matter what regulator you place in between, you will NEVER get more time then 20 minute with that battery and that motor combination. In fact, you will have much less. Each regulators will have an efficiency level that will diminish this time. A regulator doesn't add power, it changes the voltage and current but it never adds any power.